# Viewstate verification failed. Reason: The viewstate supplied failed integrity check

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, web-config, web-farm

It's been a while that I'm getting "Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster." error on GridView post-backs.

I've defined the same machine-keys on my sites but I **(sometimes)** get the message.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your web.config file in the system.web section:

```
<machinekey validationkey="xxx" decryptionkey="xxx" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
```

Provide your own validation and decryption keys ("xxx" above),

which you can try to generated from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16645/ASP-NET-machineKey-Generator)

Please do refer this [microsoft kb](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2915218)

Comment: I've already added `<machineKey validationKey="xxx" decryptionKey="xxx" decryption="AES" />` in web.config as you can see mine doens't have `validation="SHA1"`